# Error with If/Else Statement

Tags: java, if-statement

```
public class proj22
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   float degreef, degreec, degree;
            string cel = "c";
            string far = "f";
            string unit;
            System.out.println("Enter a temperture:");
            scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
            degree = keyboard.nextFloat();
            System.out.println("Enter a c to designate Celsius, or an f to designate..");        
            unit = keyboard.next();
            if (unit.equalsIgnoreCase(cel)||unit.equalsIgnoreCase(far))
            {
                    if (unit.equalsIgnoreCase(cel))
                    {
                            degreec = 5*(degreef-32)/9;
                            System.out.println("The degree you entered in Celsius is" + 
                            System.out.println("The degree you entered in Fahrenheit" + 

                    }
                    else
                            degreef = degree;
                            degreef = (9*(degreec/5)+32);
                            System.out.println("The degree you entered in Fahrenheit" + 
                            degreec + "C");

            else
                    System.out.println("Error: incorrect letter usage.");

            }
    }
}
```

This code functions properly except in line 27 there is an error when compiling stating that:

```
"proj22.java:27: error: 'else' without 'if'
        else
        ^

1 error"
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You forgot the brackets at the inner else-statement

Comment: In the future, somehow identify (eg, with `<<== line 27`) the line that the error message names.  Otherwise you may find your question closed as "off topic".

Comment: And get in the habit of ALWAYS using `{}` with if/else clauses, even for single lines where it's theoretically not necessary.

Comment: Easy question gets a -1 but easy answer gets +3 ?

Answer (score 5):

When you have a multiline `if`, `else`, `for`, etc., you need to add brackets, so that they become a block and are interpreted by the compiler as a single statement:

```
else
{//you need to add a bracket here
    degreef = degree;
    degreef = (9*(degreec/5)+32);
    System.out.println("The degree you entered in Fahrenheit" + 
    degreec + "C");
}//and here
```

Also, the bracket after the last else should be moved before it.

Comment: Nit-pick:  the if-part (consequent) and else-part (alternative) are always single statements.  `{ ... }` is a single statement.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor better?

Comment: The comment was more for the benefit of the OP, than a request for improvement, to be honest.  For improvement though, I'd remove the term "multiline", since Java doesn't care about lines.  It cares about statements.  The consequent and alternative are single statements.  If you want to execute multiple statements, then they have to be combined into a single statement.  I don't think the answer necessarily needs to be improved;  I just think that it's better to have the mental model that the compiler is actually being _consistent_ about this, and not some special case where "if you only have

Comment: one statement, then you can omit the curly braces", which is how many less-experienced programmers seem to view it.  It's not a special case;  there always has to be exactly one statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if-else` statements are invalid. What IDE are you using? Normally if there is a formatting error in the code the IDE won't let you run the program until the errors have been fixed.

A proper `if-else` statement is as follows:

```
if (condition) {
   //statements
} else if (condition) {
   //statements
} else {
   //statements
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has to look like this (check comments in code for explanation):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{//Beginning of method  
    float degreef, degreec, degree;
    string cel = "c";
    string far = "f";
    string unit;
    System.out.println("Enter a temperture:");
    scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    degree = keyboard.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Enter a c to designate Celsius, or an f to designate..");        
    unit = keyboard.next();
    if (unit.equalsIgnoreCase(cel)||unit.equalsIgnoreCase(far))
    {//Beginning of first(1) if-statement
        if (unit.equalsIgnoreCase(cel))
        {//Beginning of second(2)/inner if-statement
            degreec = 5*(degreef-32)/9;
            System.out.println("The degree you entered in Celsius is" + 
            System.out.println("The degree you entered in Fahrenheit" + 
        }//End of second/inner if-statement
        else
        {//Begin-bracket for multi-line else        
            degreef = degree;
            degreef = (9*(degreec/5)+32);
            System.out.println("The degree you entered in Fahrenheit" + 
            degreec + "C");
        }//End-bracket for multi-line else  
    } //Needed to add this bracket to close first(1) if-statement
    else //*You could add a '{' here
        System.out.println("Error: incorrect letter usage.");
    //if you add a bracket at the beginning of else you'll have to close it here with '}'
    //removed bracket here
}//End of Method
```

As mentioned you need to surround multineline else-statements with brackets. 
Further you need to close your first if-statement before your else-statement.